# Is it possible that a series of Feynman diagrams converge?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

**A bit of maybe unnecessary context**

I'm reading [*"Lecture notes on Diagrammatic Monte Carlo for the Frohlich polaron"*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.03044). It says

> It is usually unknown whether a series converges or not. The series is guaranteed to diverge at a phase transition, but it may happen sooner. In fact, most series in physics are asymptotic, which can be established rigorously in a number of cases

**Question:**
I take this as an indication that a series of Feynman diagrams may converge. However, I can't really make sense of it. To me it seems that no matter the system considered, each diagram will consist of a small parameter $u^N$. This parameter suppresses the importance of each diagram exponentially. However, for every(?) diagrammatic series the number of diagrams increases factorially. It now seems to me that for any finite $u$ the series will diverge, because the factorial number of diagrams always "beats" the expontential supressing.

I am not really sure how to understand this, but suspect I might have a wrong understanding of what is meant by convergence it this case.

In addition, I am aware of Dyson's argument that when the series is not analytic for a coupling constant equal to zero, the series will diverge. Hence, this question is only relevant when Dyson's argument does not apply.

Comment: I think there is a problem here with defining what *series* of diagrams converges and in what sense. Resummation of (sub)series of diagrams is a standard procedure which results in finite answers, e.g. summing ring diagrams (RPA) or summing ladder diagrams. One also often speaks about *summing the most divergent diagrams*.

Comment: In my question I am talking about summing all diagrams, not only subseries. And it seems to me that this entire sum never converges. But this might not be what is meant by convergence by others?

Comment: [All Feynman diagram series with non-zero coupling constants diverge](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/string+theory+FAQ#NonConvergenceOfPerturbationSeries) (Dyson 52, Lipatov 77).  This is not due to “the factorial beating the exponential,” but because a non-zero radius of converge would yield correlators for negative couplings.  _Optimal truncation_ describes when to truncate [divergent series](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/asymptotic+expansion) to most accurately calculate the “actual” value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These series are power series like $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n g^n$ in some coupling $g$. Power series are special, versus all series in that one has a priori a good understanding of what can possibly happen. Namely, the radius of convergence $R$ defined by
$$
R=\frac{1}{\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} |a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}}
$$
with the convention that $1/0=\infty$ and $1/\infty=0$, is such that the following holds.

1. If $|g|>R$ the series is trivially divergent, i.e., the general term $a_n g^n$ does not converge to zero.
2. If $|g|<R$ the series converges and does so absolutely, i.e., $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n g^n|<\infty$.

Now for typical Feynman diagram power series, $a_n=\sum_D b_D$ is a finite sum over diagrams $D$. Figuring out the size $|a_n|$ is more complicated than just counting how many $D$'s there are at a certain order $n$ in perturbation theory. This number is typically factorial, but there can be cancellations so that $|\sum_D b_D|$ ends up being much smaller than $\sum_D |b_D|$. Moreover, the contributions of the diagrams do not have the same size.

Now for a Bosonic theory like Euclidean $\phi^4$ with cutoffs, at fixed $n$, the $b_D$ are real numbers and they all have the *same sign*, so there cannot be any cancellations. If one neglects the variation of size of diagram contributions, one gets a rough estimate
$$
|a_n|\sim \frac{1}{n!}\times \frac{(4n)!}{2^{2n}(2n)!}\sim n!
$$
ignoring anything of the form $C^n$.
This results in $R=0$ and divergence of the series, no matter how small the coupling $g$ is.

For Fermionic theories, there are cancellations. In the fact, in the presence of cutoffs (UV and IR), the series is convergent for $g$ small, i.e., $R>0$.

Another notable model where the perturbation series converges in a very subtle way is the dipole gas. See

- K. Gawedzski and A. Kupiainen, ["Block spin renormalization group for dipole gas and $(\nabla\varphi)^4$"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0003491683900714) in Ann. Phys.
- K. Gawedzski and A. Kupiainen, ["Lattice dipole gas and $(\nabla\varphi)^4$
  models at long distances: decay of correlations and scaling limit"](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103940930) in CMP.

Also note that Dyson's argument is nowhere near being a proof, it is just some handwavy heuristic. Finally, to get a better feel for these convergence issues, and resummation techniques like Borel's method, it is good to consider the pedagogical example of QFT in zero dimension as explained in: Rivasseau, ["Constructive Field Theory in Zero Dimension"](https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.3524).

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the answer I was looking for. By cutoffs, do you mean setting a cutoff on the limit of the integrals in order to avoid infrared and ultraviolet divergencies, or do you mean something else?

Comment: Thanks. What you said is a bit contradictory. By cutoff I mean ultraviolet cutoff and also finite volume cutoff. "setting a cutoff on the limit of the integral" is something completely different called a large field cutoff, i.e., in a functional integral over $\phi$ instead of allowing all values restricting to $\phi\in[-L,L]$ for some finite $L$. If one does this the perturbation series converges for trivial reasons and one simply dodged/avoided the issue entirely.

Answer (score 0):

The discussion in question deals with resummation of the diagrammatic series for a partition function. If the Hamiltonian and the phase space are properly defined, the partition function is finite. The non-convergence problem here is expanding a function at the point of its non-analiticity (e.g., one cannot expand $\log x$ or $1/x$ around $x=0$), and we do not know in advance whether it is analytical or not, as a function of the small parameter. We certainly know that it is non-analytical in the vicinity of a phase transition.

Comment: So the expression we are expanding may of course be finite, some correlation- or partition function. It is, however, not clear to me whether the corresponding series may converge, although it is very clear that in some cases it diverges.

Comment: You are speaking specifically about the series of Feynmann diagrams? Do you already have an experience with Feynman-Dyson expansion?

Comment: Yes, so my question is on the actural series. I have learned that although the series diverges it might give useful information as it often diverges asymptotically. But I don't understand what is meant by a convergent series.

Comment: Knowing *how* the series diverges is often useful. E.g., the logarithmic divergence in the Kondo problem prompted deeper studies and eventual solution via other methods (renormalization group, Bethe ansatz, etc.) One can even formally sum divergent series.

Note that the number of Feynmann diagrams does not grow factorially: some of them are cancelled  out, whereas others are often typologically identical. For a Green's function the identical diagrams cancel factor $1/n!$ in the expansion of the exponent, whereas for a partition function they cancel it partially.

Comment: So, in conclusion, a convergent series means that the number of Feynman diagrams effectively does not increase factorially, due to cancellations?

Comment: The number of diagrams does not increase factorially. But note also that diagrams are just a representation of the terms of expansion $\langle e^x\rangle = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{ \langle x^n\rangle}{n!}$. Expansion of an exponent is itself convergent, it is the averaging term by term that may produce divergences.