# How can we calculate autocorrelation?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, computational-physics, statistics

In a Markov chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) algorithm, autocorrelation is a measure of correlation between subsequent measurements. This is in many cases quantified by considering the correlation between some observables corresponding to each measurement.

However, in some MCMC algorithms, such as diagrammatic Monte Carlo, one does not have an observable associated with each measurement, and I can imagine this is the case for many types of MCMC approaches. How can we calculate autocorrelation in such a case?

Comment: Migrate to cross validated? Bit confused by notion of observable/measurement in the context of autocorrelation of MCMC samples

Comment: @innisfree I think the question is really about the diagrammatic MC - this is very much physics (or mathematical methods for physics).

Comment: Ok, diagrammatic MC = diagrammatic Markov Chain?

Comment: What I am really interested in is Diagrammatic Monte Carlo, which is a specific type of Markov chain Monte Carlo algorithm. This is more clearly stated in the latest edit.

Comment: ok. does the diagrammatic MC generate samples from a particular distribution, like ordinary MCMC?

Comment: Yes, and each sample corresponds to a Feynman diagram with a particular value for each internal variable. The weight of the state is proportional to the absolute value of this particular value of the integrand.

Comment: @innisfree you can look at the reference in B.Brekke's other post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/551375/247642
Apparently this is a new numerical technique... rather interesting, although I am not sure how useful or widespread.